# Flutter slider bar animation

Tags: android, flutter, animation, dart

I wrote this code that is basically a slide bar with a fixed value between 0 and 100. When I press the shuffle button its value (`jovirometro.toDouble` variable) changes. All I wish to make is an animation that slides from a value to other. The user doesn't interact with the slider.

Here's how it looks now
[image: Here's how it looks now]

```
child: Container(
  height: 10,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.1),
    gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          Colors.red,
          Colors.redAccent,
          Colors.white,
          Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          Colors.green
        ]
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  ),
  child: SliderTheme(
    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
      activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
      inactiveTrackColor: Colors.white,
      trackHeight: 0.1,
      thumbColor: Colors.white,
      thumbShape: CustomSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 10),
      overlayColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(1),
    ),
    child: Slider(
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: jovirometro.toDouble(),
      onChanged: (value){setState((){});},
    ),
  ),
),
```

The jovirometro's variable is

```
var jovirometro = snapshot.data.documents[_word]['jovirometro'];
```

from the Firestore server, and the shuffle button changes the "_word" parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue and managed to solved mine with `AnimatedBuilder`.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 10,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.1),
                gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                  Colors.red,
                  Colors.redAccent,
                  Colors.white,
                  Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                  Colors.green
                ]),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: _animationController,
                builder: (_, __) {
                  return SliderTheme(
                    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                      activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                      inactiveTrackColor: Colors.white,
                      trackHeight: 0.1,
                      thumbColor: Colors.white,
                      overlayColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(1),
                    ),
                    child: Slider(
                      value: _animationController.value,
                      onChanged: null,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _animationController.animateTo(Random().nextDouble());
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.autorenew),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've created a codepen based on your code and my solution to it.

https://codepen.io/pczn0327/pen/XWXYKap

Comment: Thanks man!! Your answer helped me figure out what's going on with my code

Answer (score 2):

Before asking here on SO you should do some research to try to solve the problem yourself. Flutter provides excellent documentation in my opinion and even has an [Animations tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial) that would have been of great help to you.

For your case you should use an [`AnimationController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html).

You need to add `with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` to your `State` of your `StatefulWidget`, instantiate the controller in `initState`, and add a listener to call `setState` on value changes:

```
_controller = AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: widget.duration,
  upperBound: 100.0,
);
..addListener(() {
  setState(() {
  });
```

and `dispose` it in `dispose`:

```
_controller.dispose();
```

You can use `_controller.value` to get the current value of your animation, which should be passed to the `Slider`:

```
child: Slider(
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  value: _controller.value,
  onChanged: (value){setState((){});},
),
```

Now whenever you want to animate the value of the slider call `animateTo`, or one of the many methods of animating with the `AnimationController`, setting the `target` as your intended value, and optionally setting the `Duration` and `Curve` of the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Acctualy I have tried this approach, but only animates the first value. When I click the button the value change but it doesn't animate

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: You're not correctly using the `AnimationController` for your purposes. Pleas **thoroughly** read my answer.

Comment: Sorry man, I really don't know what is wrong, pls explain me

Comment: I would recommend removing all of your current animation code and starting over starting with what I have in my answer. There are major differences that I describe. There are also no mentions or code of a button anywhere. Please show some of that code and elaborate.

Comment: There are multiple buttons. Please specify what you are referring to and review my answer again. All elements of my answer need to be considered. SImply copy-pasting my code blocks will not result in a working animation.